# Determinant of a matrix with odd diagonal and even entries

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying the solve the following problem linear algebra problem and I'm not sure where to begin:

Let $B$ be a square matrix with n columns and integer entries. This matrix is constructed so that all diagonal entries are odd and all other entries are even. We wish to demonstrate that $\det(B) \neq 0$.

My knee jerk is to separate $B$ into even and odd matrices $B_{even}$ and $B_{odd}$, where $B_{odd}$ will be diagonal and have a nonzero determinant. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determinant is the sum of products of elements taken from one column and one row. All of these products are even except one, that taken from the diagonal. Thus $\det B$ is odd. Alternatively, you could use induction and expand along the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to show that is by using the fact that if a square matrix $B$ has integer entries then:
$$(det(B)) mod \;2=det(B\; mod\: 2)$$
$B \;mod \; 2=I$ and so $0 \neq det(I)=det(B \; mod \; 2)=det(B) \; mod \; 2$, so we have that $det(B) \neq 0.$

Comment: Can you please tell me why : $(det(B)) mod \;2=det(B\; mod\: 2)$?

Answer (score 0):

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \color{red}{odd} & even & \dots & even\\
    even & odd & \dots & even \\ 
    \vdots & \ddots & \dots & even\\
    even & even &even & odd 
    \end{bmatrix}$$

$$|B| = \color{red}{odd} + even+even+..........+even=odd\ne 0$$